# How to replace any one of many possible matches in bash

Tags: bash, replace

I want to reduce this down to one line:

```
item=${_menu_sel_value/M--/}
item=${item/-M-/}
item=${item/D--/}
item=${item/-D-/}
item=${item/??-/}
```

Here is a test sample. User chooses one of the following from a shell menu and their choice is passed into bash script code above (so, only need to match ONE of the possibilities):

```
 -D-branch.sh
 M--cfg/aliases.cfg
 -M-functions/0300.menu.sh
 M--git_aliases.sh
 ??-add.sh
```

Is it possible?

I tried something like:

```
item=${_menu_sel_value/^[M\-]/}
```

But it didn't work.

Comment: What are some typical values of `_menu_sel_value`? It's not clear if more than one substitution is possible, or if the order in which you try the substitutions is important (it may be, since you only substitute the first of each match found).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is what you are looking for.

```
shopt -s extglob
item=${_menu_sel_value/@(M--|-M-|D--|-D-|\?\?-)/}
```

The pattern `@(a|b|c)` matches any one of the patterns `a`, `b`, or `c`. Note the need to escape the `?`, as it is a wildcard that matches any single character in a pattern.

Answer (score 0):

If you know that you'll always have the first three characters that need to be stripped off, you can just use a substring operation:

```
item=${_menu_sel_value:3}
```